# Python openpyxl module says: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'upper'

Tags: python, tuples, export-to-excel, attributeerror, openpyxl

Installed Python 3.4 and modules `jdcal` and `openpyxl`:

Trying myself on the `openpyxl` library to read and write XLSX files from Python. I installed the `jdcall` module and the `openpyxl` module. Code lets me create the workbook and work sheet:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb  = Workbook()
ws  = wb.active
```

However, if I try to write to the first cell like this:

```
ws[ 1, 1]   = 'testing 1-2-3'
```

Python says:

> ```
> C:\Wolf\Python Studies>database.py
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "C:\Wolf\Python Studies\database.py", line 13, in <module>
>    ws[ 1, 1]   = 'testing 1-2-3'
>  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-2.2.0b1-py3.4.egg\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 403, in __setitem__
>    self[key].value = value
>  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-2.2.0b1-py3.4.egg\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 400, in __getitem__ <BR>
>    return self._get_cell(key)
>  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-2.2.0b1-py3.4.egg\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 368, in _get_cell
>    coordinate = coordinate.upper()
> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'upper'
>
> C:\Wolf\Python Studies>
> ```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You need to specify the coordinate as a string (e.g. `A1`) and not as indices.

Answer (score 7):

Cell coordinates should be provided *as a string*:

```
ws['A1'] = 'testing 1-2-3'
```

Or, if you want to use row and column indexes, use `ws.cell().value`:

```
ws.cell(row=1, column=1).value = 'testing 1-2-3'
```

Comment: This exception is also thrown when you try to assign data to row "A0".